# Is it possible to assign the field type dynamically - Django Form?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

Is it possible to assign the field type dynamically - Django Form?

```
field_type = 'CharField'

field = forms.{field_type}(label='Field')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) like so

```
field_type = 'CharField'

field = getattr(forms, field_type)(label='Field')
```

Just make sure that `field_type` is a valid Django form field name.

Comment: Its Work Jamie. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.